# load into the next element

Tags: jquery

I would like the follow code to load a series of "holder" classes. However the after() method seems to be nesting the holders.

**Current code**

```
<div class="holder" >
    <a href="test.html" class="link">lorem ipsum</a><br />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 

        $('.link').click(function (event) {
            var newHolder = $('.holder').after()
            newHolder.load(this.href);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });       

    });
</script>
```

** Desired output **

```
<div class="holder"></div>
<div class="holder"></div>
<div class="holder"></div>
<div class="holder"></div>
```

etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the simplest way to achieve the output you want might be this:

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().after('<div class="holder"></div>').load(this.href);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to be after the current link, this will take you up the DOM tree one level, to the current `div.holder` and then to the next `.holder`, then call load.

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    var div = $('<div/>',{"class":"holder"}).load(this.href);
    $(this).parent().after(div);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Edit: Misunderstood, the div needs to be created, yes?

Answer (score 1):

[jQuery's `.after()` method](http://api.jquery.com/after/) "inserts content, specified by the parameter, after each element in the set of matched elements".  It sounds like the correct API call, for the objective you described.

However, I see two problems with how you are using it.

1. There is a syntax error when you omitted the `;` after the `after()` call.  This could potentially have the effect of causing a JavaScript error which makes the script terminate.
2. You do not pass an argument to the `after` call.  It is not clear that the way you are using it should return a new holder object.  I'm still not completely clear on what you are trying to do, but I think this might work better:

   ```
   $('.link').click(function (event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       var linkHref = this.href;
       $('.holder').each(function(){
                 $this = $(this);
                 var $clone = $this.clone();
                 $clone.load(linkHref);
                 $this.after($clone);
             });
       return false;
   });
   ```

Can you post a more complete code sample (or jsFiddle) including the HTML DOM sample so we can see what exactly is happening incorrectly?